# Extract data with Simple HTML DOM Parser + Function call

Tags: javascript, php, simple-html-dom

I was trying to extract data with Simple HTML DOM parser but some of the datafields I was retreiving was empty. So I realised that the page Im fetching the data from is using an function call to populate the data.

After viewing the source code on the page I saw that they are using the 
$(document).ready(), and the function I assume popoulates the data inside there.

So my question is how to realise the function call in similar way to populate the data and then fetching the data with DOM parser?

When Im trying to call the function in the console mode it works, so I just need to do this but programatically from the PHP script Im using.

This is what I want to do, but I know it wont work, but you get my intention hopefully:

```
$html= file_get_html($siteURL);

echo "function populateData(){
    registerData(x,y,z);
}"

echo "populateData()";

//now fetch newly populated data by html dom parser
$data=$html->find('div[class=box1a]');
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! Well, it seems you're mixing client and server side code. The `populateData` function is only called when the page is rendered in a browser. When the execution of your code reaches the `$html->find` call, the contents from `$siteURL` were not changed by that Javascript function. I think this answer can give you a good perspective on that matter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10326818/1128918

Comment: Oh thanks for that!